# Not able to see "Change field type" button. Master doesn't have any Rollup summary field

Tags: lookup

I have an object with a master-detail relationship field with no rollup summary field on master. Still I am not able to see "Change field type" button to change it to lookup. Can someone let me know how to make "Change field type" visible in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the Approval Process so it doesn't rely on the Master2 object or fields. Then, you'll be able to change the Master2 relationship.

```
 Setup > App Setup > Go To your object > Click "Edit" on Master Detail Field > Click on "Change Field Type" > Select Lookup Relationship > Save it.
```